# How to map a different JSON response for GET request with optional URL parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit, restkit-0.20

I need to perform a GET request to a url, with optional URL parameters.

The basic URL looks something like `http://host/user/explore`, with the option of querying `http://host/user/explore?who=VALUE&category=VALUE&service=VALUE` for more accurate results.

For the first case the response comes with keys at the root, such as:

```
{
  "professionals": [
    {
        "_id": "59e8576cb524cf44a435844b"
    }
   ],
 "salons": [
    {
        "_id": "59e857bbb524cf44a4358454"
    }
   ]
}
```

And I am able of successfully mapping the response by setting up my response descriptor such as:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *response = [RKResponseDescriptor
                                  responseDescriptorWithMapping:[Explore map1]
                                  method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                  pathPattern:@"user/explore"
                                  keyPath:nil                    
       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
return response;
```

(note that the `[Explore map1]` accounts for mapping an NSArray of "Professional" and another one made up of "Salon" NSObjects)

However, when I query `http://host/user/explore?who=VALUE&category=VALUE&service=VALUE`, my response JSON becomes:

```
{
  "_id": "59f6f9fc36e51720da2e85f4"
},
{
  "_id": "92x2f9fc36e51720da2e66d5"
}
```

Where the actual returned objects are all of the same type (and no longer have a key at the root).

So now obviously, my `RKResponseDescriptor` and `RKObjectMapping` are failing to properly handle this case.

I've looked into using `RKDynamicMapping` or `RKRoute` and wasn't able of really getting a handle on how they work or if they're even applicable to my case...

Answer (score 0):

you url is: http://host/user/explore?who=VALUE&category=VALUE&service=VALUE
so just do as this:

```
    let postMapping: RKObjectMapping = RKObjectMapping(for: GetFoo.self)
    postMapping.addAttributeMappings(from:["who","category","service"])

    // Define response decriptor

    let statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClass.successful)
    let resDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: postMapping, method: RKRequestMethod.GET, pathPattern: "user/explore", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: statusCodes)

    // Create object manager

    let url = URL(string: "http://host")

    let jsonPlaceholderManager = RKObjectManager(baseURL: url)
    jsonPlaceholderManager?.addResponseDescriptor(resDescriptor)
    RKObjectManager.setShared(jsonPlaceholderManager)

    RKObjectManager.shared().getObjectsAtPath("/user/explore?who=VALUE&category=VALUE&service=VALUE", parameters: nil, success: { (operation, mappingResult) -> Void in

        let dataResponse = operation?.httpRequestOperation.responseData
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSMutableDictionary
        print(dataResponse)
```